# If I close a terminal does it kill the processes inside of it?

Tags: gnome-terminal

If I am in the middle of using the terminal, say to `apt-get` something;

If I click the **x** / **close** button, does the Terminal continue to run in the background?

[image]

To afraid to try it, cause I don't want to have to start the process all over again...

Has anyone accidentally done it?

Comment: If you close the terminal you will kill any processes you started with it.  But you can break this link with the **disown** command see duplicate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the Terminal will be closed, then the bash process will terminate (because of [SIGHUP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#POSIX_signals)), then apt-get will terminate in turn.

Comment: @ingis Thank you for the answer. I have always wondered that...